# Torque Control of DC fan using Arduino

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, fan, torque

I am trying to control the torque of a 24V-DC fan ([datasheet](http://portal.sunon.com.tw/pls/portal/sunonap.sunon_html_d_pkg.open_file?input_file_name=7264646F632F3230313730392F3236303132312F28443039303338393330472D3031292D302E706466)) using an arduino. A control system with feedback must be setup to continuously check the torque of the motor and correct it, if the value isn't desired. Currently, I have an ACS-712 set up in series with the fan to measure the current through the fan because I know torque and current are proportional. The reading from the current sensor will go into the arduino as an input. This is where I am stuck now. Once the arduino gets the current reading, what do I need to be able to actually change the torque of the fan. I have read that I may need an H-bridge to do this, or some kind of motor driver. What do i need to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most fans like this already have a BLDC motor controller built into the fan. You can't control the torque unless you rip out the existing controller and replace it with your own. You can possibly control the speed by varying the DC voltage you supply to the controller.

Comment: You don't need a full H bridge. Just a single mosfet and an LC output filter. You are making a buck converter (non synchronous) and controlling the switch duty cycle with your arduino.

Comment: Unless your current error tolerance is high, you must use a linear method to sense and control current. What is your spec?  PWM will add a lot of noise. at 1kHz or add significant problems with filtering and add start surge current or resonance issues with fan commutation (acoustics)

Comment: What are your controlled design spec tolerances?

Comment: As it only has 2 wires, you'll need to vary the voltage you supply to it, within the specified voltage range, probably by PWM (you could use a buck convertor for the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2W DC fan that internally uses Hall sensors to commutate the 2 pole winding  drivers as a BLDC motor.  Above stall speed, I have found that the motor current is roughly  proportional to voltage up to its rated voltage so you could say it appears  like a resistor with a capacitive load that with rapid supply increases demands more current until the fan reaches its steady-state RPM producing a Back EMF to reduce the current. The fan air loading applied creates air pressure which will increases the current slightly and then reduces the RPM and air flow velocity.

What you need is an adjustable linear current driver and linear current sensor. You can define your target torque (current) and make a linear transfer function and avoid the hassles I have found with LC PWM causing ripple and interfering with motor BLDC operation with acoustic noise.

It might look something like this. (Always start with design specs)

### SPECS

- Current regulate a 24V 2W (~<90mA) fan  with <2% error.
- estimated stall/start voltage where stall voltage might be around 20%  (TBD)
- design control current method with input from 0 to 3V with a linear voltage controlled current
- design sense current from an amplified small R current shunt with 50mV drop at max (100mA) and differential amplifier that senses near 0V.
- design driver circuit to be a voltage-controlled current sink with an error Op Amp to match load current to control voltage.
- choose a control slope like Vctl=3V for 100mA  (with 10% headroom to 3.3V) or k=30mV/mA

### or plan B (Change design spec)

- Scale Analog control voltage for current down to match R Current sensor voltage = 500mV max.
- Use comparator or Op Amp to drive Nch logic level FET (<1 Ohm) for low side current control with sensing near 0V, single supply.
- Model Fan load then simulate
  Feel free to change my specs to yours.  [Here's 1 of many ways to do this with a FET < 1 Ohm](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwrLAWAnC1bUgIwDZIA5MB2BTE7WTPBRWEbCW2BgUwFpNMAoAJToQgBMYPCEJCQQkRAj8JCcArCRYnAGYgECEQIHytg3SADMArMqycAxiFj05EbLN3SoMTCHax8BTdiTYBQkJsMXclN04AczphCTwRehEjMHlpTgAnPkFY22ypOLBOAHcbO0kbTFNygWKNPEF4usEnWqNYKsa2qrFwWsc8rPtekq6JHtHnYdKGkX04kS5M3PmY7UbpZU4AQ2N2iUMEE335JBsFTBhLjbABPDakMRDMJB1MIyNCV1uPu8Jf-6MCyuhRKc1uST24N6mSh1VsEliEAulwyK2qjShSMIKmisIxnRSilakNisNJtU02gORx08hqvBwBnkHCqhggRigAncmHMPNoGxUAA8bHsiA5DlhCBzmXSAOoAHQAzgAhAAyABEAMJK1RbAB2nAARjZkJLsHQytgpBT6giRBQqojastyi7ZIV%20NL-FhzYRCaRUhoAPqOINgINaKVh6BuaPCRBSlLPK3YQF4ARhoMZhBBoycT0gb222lYTTnJAhnPhw6IIOwaOYTMZ565zjCqhYPDmxmd04ykCKorMZgAByVABdmIrx-mwNLbcl5IljFaFDpK5ma0Y47GlDh90RsFbNLAjBwm1mM3miFV4dVSYjRGZyGcXEpaAA1AD2ABtx1tImYNs6C5CQkAgAhTgEJBpVLEBuCVeUAEclUwAB6BAlQVRVVC-dIlU1ABXdJ0mYPVxyVABlMjFSAr8sFORwFBreR%20UgMIJAY4xOHozBaCYpEBEQc1wm%20P4fgk8SpBjMBuU4vjuN49wBKwISEBE6BvlgB4BCeF4uXeT5wjcTjTA4RSND4J8WI0DZ3A5dwBE2IA)